# Not able to send gif images to whatsapp bot through integration

Tags: gif, whatsapp

We are using https://graph.facebook.com/phonenumber/messages along with payload to push response to whatsapp bot. We are able to send png, jpeg images, but not able to send gif images to whatsapp bot.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#supported-media-types) the Supported Media Types for Image:

| Media | Supported Types | Size Limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| image | image/jpeg, image/png | 5MB |

Thre is no option to send .gif type media.